# Ubuntu Server 12.04 and 14.04 LTS compatibilty and reason for upgrade

Tags: 12.04, server, upgrade

I have few servers running Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS and now I will be expanding on few more, both of my dedicated server providers offer new Ubuntu releases, why should I install version 14? I do not need it but maybe I am overseeing something.

I am mostly using Apache, Bind9, Cron, MySQL, PHP, Rsync and SSH. Is it going to be all compatible and working together? Anybody had any conflicts or issues, something working very different?

When I run ubuntu-support-status, I get some unsupported packages, is it worth looking into this stuff from security point of view? Security updates should be supported until April 2017.

```
$ ubuntu-support-status 

Support status summary of 'server X':

You have 47 packages (2.4%) supported until October 2013 (18m)
You have 9 packages (0.5%) supported until December 2016 (18m)
You have 1673 packages (84.5%) supported until April 2017 (5y)

You have 5 packages (0.3%) that can not/no-longer be downloaded
You have 246 packages (12.4%) that are unsupported
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why should I install version 14? I do not need it but maybe I am overseeing something.

If there is no feature or software in the newer version that you need, then the only reason in favour of upgrading will be that it will be supported for longer, so instead of losing support in April 2017, you'll lose support in April 2019.

> I am mostly using Apache, Bind9, Cron, MySQL, PHP, Rsync and SSH. Is it going to be all compatible and working together? Anybody had any conflicts or issues, something working very different?

All of these will continue to be supported in 14.04, and between those two versions any required configuration changes should be minimal.  Obviously you still need to properly research and test that, though, so there is a definite cost to upgrading that needs to be balanced with the benefit.

> When I run ubuntu-support-status, I get some unsupported packages, is it worth looking into this stuff from security point of view?

It's worth looking into these.  It sounds like you have a mix of packages from previous versions of Ubuntu, including non-LTS versions, that weren't upgraded properly or were removed in the newer versions.

In particular, you have 47+9 packages from other non-LTS versions of Ubuntu, which should be upgraded or removed.  You have 5 packages that are not included in Ubuntu (or no longer included in Ubuntu) some of which may need to be removed, unless you get them from a third party eg PPA and you trust that PPA to support them, and you have 246 that are unsupported - I presume this means they're from the universe respository in which case that's better than nothing.